# playing Urban Terror on Ubuntu 14.04, while in Urban Terror the mouse is jerky & slow

Tags: 14.04, mouse, games, urban-terror

I'm using lenovo thinkpad x250 with Ubuntu 14.04, trying to play Urban Terror but my mouse is acting funny while in play. on regular desktop session my mouse is acting as normal as I can see. But then while entering the game it becomes slow, or not translating the movement correctly: a full brush of the mouse will translate to a smaller move on the screen.

what I got:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer      (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave      pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G300s Optical Gaming Mouse       id=9    [slave      pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave      pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=15   [slave      pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=16   [slave      pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard     (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G300s Optical Gaming Mouse       id=10   [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400              id=11   [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave      keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=17   [slave      keyboard (3)]
```

Any suggestions?

some of the output of Urban Terror if it might help:

```
14187 files in pk3 files
execing default.cfg
"MINUS" isn't a valid key
"PLUS" isn't a valid key
execing q3config.cfg
couldn't exec autoexec.cfg
Minimum com_hunkMegs is 512, allocating 512 megs.
Hunk_Clear: reset the hunk ok
----- Client Initialization -----
Couldn't read q3history.
----- Initializing Renderer ----
-------------------------------
QKEY found.
----- Client Initialization Complete -----
----- R_Init -----
...loading libGL.so.1:
Calling SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)...
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) passed.
Initializing OpenGL display
...setting mode 16: 1920 1080
Using 4/4/4 Color bits, 24 depth, 0 stencil display.
GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Broadwell 
Initializing OpenGL extensions
...ignoring GL_S3_s3tc
...ignoring GL_EXT_texture_env_add
...using GL_ARB_multitexture
...using GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array
...ignoring GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic

GL_VENDOR: Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Broadwell 
GL_VERSION: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
GL_MAX_ACTIVE_TEXTURES_ARB: 8

PIXELFORMAT: color(32-bits) Z(24-bit) stencil(0-bits)
MODE: 16, 1920 x 1080 windowed hz:N/A
GAMMA: hardware w/ 0 overbright bits
CPU: 
rendering primitives: single glDrawElements
texturemode: GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR
picmip: 1
texture bits: 32
multitexture: enabled
compiled vertex arrays: enabled
texenv add: disabled
compressed textures: disabled
XF86VidModeSetGamma: 1.771, 1.771, 1.771.
Initializing Shaders
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try raise mouse sensitivity from:

  Setup → Controls → Misc → Sensitivity
- If it did not work, then may be one of the other point devices is very sensitive so it affect your mouse movement or even shoot (1st button click) like mine.

  Check them one by one:

  - `xinput --disable "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`
  - `xinput --disable "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"`
  - `xinput --disable "ELAN Touchscreen"`

  To enable it back use:

  ```
  xinput --enable <devicename>
  ```